Dynamic Routes in Rails
I have a Help File system that is quite lengthy.  It will be governed by its own controller-model-view that will show the various help pages as the user clicks on the corresponding link.  The client wants the help page to show in the URL [ex. https://sitename.test/help/HELP_FILE_NAME_HERE].
I am thinking a dynamic route in [routes.rb] would do the trick.  How can I accomplish this when there is a fluid number of pages based on an evolving help system?

Where are these help files stored? i.e. how do you know what the valid HELP_FILE_NAME_HERE values are?

Without building an entire CMS, they will live in the database for this version.  I can refer to them via a plug that can be built into the db schema.  Each help page will be CRUD-able through the normal verbs.

If your slugs are of the usual format then you have get '/help/:slug' and the duplicate that @dbugger pointed out
